# How change where the icon show

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have Angular js table, I want to add a text field to include the filter/search functionality but the automatic icon is showing wrong place

This is my view

```
<table>
 <theader>
   <tr>
      <th at-attribute="Car_ID">
          Test <br /> 
          <input type="text" id="filter_id" ng-model="filter_id" />
      </th> 
   </tr>
 </theader>
</table>
```

How I make the sort arrow show right next to `Test`. I guess would look better there. Unless I overreacting. Or how I create another `<tr>` below the first one to show the `search texts`?

[image]

This is the render html, the `<i>` element is autogenerated for the `angular-table`.

```
<th at-attribute="Car_ID" ng-click="predicate = 'Car_ID'; descending = !descending;" width="">
     Test <br> 
     <input type="text" id="filter_id" ng-model="filter_id" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
     <i style="margin-left: 10px;" ng-class="getSortIcon('Car_ID', predicate, descending)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
</th>
```

Comment: I don't understand. It is shown after test. Can you show on the picture where do you want to render icon?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think should be just on the right side, shouldnt be better?

Comment: what generates the icon?

Comment: @mtb `angular-table` http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the generated icon with css and replicate your own so that you can place it wherever you like and have full control.

Let's face it, hacking these plugins is never graceful so just give yourself the best opportunity to be flexible by removing the plugin's choice and handling your own.

```
<th at-attribute="Car_ID" ng-click="predicate = 'Car_ID'; descending = !descending;" width="">
  Test <i ng-class="getSortIcon('Car_ID', predicate, descending)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i><br>
  <input type="text" id="filter_id" ng-model="filter_id" />
</th>
```

css:

```
th i:last-child {
 display:none;
}
```

**edit**

This should replicate the same functionality:

```
<i ng-class="getSortIcon('Car_ID', predicate, descending)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
```

Comment: The thing is the sort arrow icon change when the header is click, how I can clone the `<i>` style?

Comment: See edit, just replicate the functionality that has been hidden

Answer (score 0):

put icon in span

```
 <i style="margin-left: 10px;" ng-class="getSortIcon('Car_ID', predicate, descending)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Icon is autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with angular, but could you try putting the input field outside/above the table header? This way it will look more uniform.

Comment: yes, I just tought on that. Still trying create another header row below. Know how to do that?

Comment: I am assuming you just tried <th></th> below the other <th></th> in the table correct? If not give that a shot, otherwise I would just put the box in <tr> </tr> tags