# will angular update one `ng-model` inside a <tfoot>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm doing angular table filter. My **[first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724089/how-change-where-the-icon-show)** is to try to include it on the header. The icon show on the wrong position and when I focus the text box the sorting change.

So I move the box to the `<tfoot>` but it looks like it is somehow disabled because even when I change the content on text box the `ng-model="filter_id"` it doesnt change.

The outside text box, works perfect.

In the picture:

- press 1 on `<tfoot input text>`: the textbox change to 1, event `updateFilteredList` trigger but `filter_id` is empty, neither `<p input text>` nor `{{filter_id}}` change.
- press 1 again on `<tfoot input text>`: the textbox change to 11, same behaviour
- press 1 on `<p input text>`: the textbox change to 1, `{{filter_id}}` update to `1` and `updateFilteredList` also receive `filter_id=1` (even when filter for 1 return the same list);

**EDIT**

I found out when app start if I type on the external text box the interal get updated. But when I type a single char on the internal one, stop the updates.

[image]

```
<div ng-controller="eventCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped" at-table at-list="filteredList" 
         at-config="config" at-paginated>
    <thead></thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" ng-change="updateFilteredList()" 
                 ng-model="filter_id" style="width: 50px" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <at-pagination at-config="config" at-list="filteredList"></at-pagination>            
  <p>
      <input type="text" ng-change="updateFilteredList()" 
       ng-model="filter_id" />
      {{filter_id}}
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm using this **[plug-in](http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html)** for my table. Is this a bug or maybe is some behaviour of the plugin? Is there a way to detect if plug-in overwrite some events?

**Controller:**

```
 app5.controller('eventCtrl', ["$scope", "$filter", "$http" , function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.cars = [
        { Car_ID: 1, X: null, Y: null, RoadName: null, Azimuth: null, DateTime: null, Adress: null }
    ];
    $scope.filteredList = $scope.cars;
    $scope.filter_id = "";

    $scope.updateFilteredList = function () {
        console.log('filter_id: ' + $scope.filter_id);
        $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_id);
        console.log('filteredList.length:' + $scope.filteredList.length);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better way, but this is working. Because the event was already triggering, I just get the value from the DOM before run the filter

```
$scope.filter_id = $('#filter_id').val();
```

**Function**

```
$scope.updateFilteredList = function () {
        $scope.filter_id = $('#filter_id').val();

        console.log('filter_id: ' + $scope.filter_id);
        $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_id);
        console.log('filteredList.length:' + $scope.filteredList.length);
    };
```

Comment: You can also use [**Angular's jqLite**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).